# TypeScript interfaces for $.extend prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, interface, prototype

I'm working on some other's project which is built in vanilla JS. As I continue the work now, I want to use TypeScript, but immediately ran into a problem: I can't use "normal" prototypal inheritance, because the former owner `Object.freeze`d the base objects. However, he himself inherited from these objects by using `$.extend(SubObject.prototype, BaseObject.prototype)` (with `$` being jQuery).

Example:

```
function BaseObject() {}

BaseObject.prototype.foo = function () { console.log("foo"); };
Object.freeze(BaseObject);

function SubObject() {}

// Now he either uses this pattern:
SubObject.prototype = $.extend({}, BaseObject);

// Or this:
$.extend(SubObject.prototype, BaseObject.prototype);
```

Since with this code base inheritance in TypeScript like `class extends BaseObject {}` does not work, I considered to keep with his pattern. But this would require me to define objects with constructors and prototype, with which I failed.

Anybody knows a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can add types here:

```
type BaseObject = { foo: () => void; };
function BaseObject(): { new() => BaseObject } {}

 BaseObject.prototype.foo = function () { console.log("foo"); };
```

Comment: Hi Jonas, thank you for the quick reply. This worked well for me... but for `const bar = new SubObject()`, bar has type `any`. Is there a way to infer the type `SubObject` without `const bar: SubObject = new SubObject()`?

Comment: @florian [read on here](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/08/22/advanced-typescript-concepts-classes-types/)

Comment: Kind of hacky, but that's works!! For now... thanks for the reference :)